# Redux getState returns initialState on server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, isomorphic-javascript

I'm building an isomorphic react app and the following tasks are performed when the user sends a request:

1) Suppose user hits `/about-us`, react-routers `matchPath` finds the appropriate component and returns it.
2) A static function named fetchData is called which dispatches an action `aboutPageContent()`. 
3) Once promise has been resolved on the server, getState gets called in order to get an updated state, **but it returns the initialState of aboutPage and not the newly updated state**.

> Reducer gets a response but does not return a new state. (this happens only when action is dispatched by server).

getState on server returns:

```
{
   aboutUs:{
      founders:[{}]
      story: ""
   }
}
```

But it should return:

```
{
  aboutUs:{
    founders:[{name: 'abc'}]
    story: "some random story"
  }
}
```

---

server.js

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {

const memoryHistory = createMemoryHistory(req.url)
const currentRoute = routes.find(r => matchPath(req.url, r))
const store = configureStore({}, memoryHistory)

if (currentRoute && currentRoute.component.fetchData) {

    Promise.all(currentRoute.component.fetchData(store, req.url)).then(() => {

        const content = (
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={{}}>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <App />
                </Provider>
            </StaticRouter>
        )

        const htmlContent = renderToString(content)

        const preloadedState = store.getState() <----- Returns initialState and not the updated state.

        const html = renderToStaticMarkup(<HtmlDocument html={htmlContent} preloadedState={preloadedState} />)

        res.status(200)
        res.send(html)
    })
}
})
```

aboutPageContainer.jsx

```
 static fetchData = (store) => [store.dispatch(aboutPageContent())]
```

---

preloadedState gets assigned to `window.__data`. And `window.__data` gets called on client.js in order to load the client store.

Am I doing anything wrong? It's my first react-isomorphic app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to subscribe to store here to get the update like below. 
using `store.subscribe` will make sure you get the updated state inside. Hope it helps. Read http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribelistener

```
 store.subscribe(() => {
 // When state will be updated(in this case, when items will be fetched), this is how we can get updated state.                    
  let items= store.getState().items;
              })
```